# unsetting array by key within WP Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post

I am trying to unset an array which has the same [key] as the post ID within a wordpress loop, using the following...

```
<form action="" method="post">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-l pull-right" type="submit" name="exerciseDelete"    value="exerciseDelete">Yes</button>
</form>

<?php $exid = the_ID() ?>

if (!empty($_POST['exerciseDelete'])) {
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
location.reload();
</script>';
unset($_SESSION['collection'][$exid]);        

}
?>
```

I have performed echo on exid at all stages on this and it is even picking up the correct title. If i hard code the $exid in the unset it works fine also.

The problem I am having is when the $_POST is sent it unsets the final key in the $*SESSION*[collection] rather than the one with the correct key.

I have had this working before now however think that this is possibly not the best method. Is there a better way of running functions on buttons rather than using $_POST??

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is doing your `post_ID()` function ?

Comment: Wordpress is giving me that within the loop it should be `the_ID` not `post_ID` will edit now.